# Read Data From All Sheets from Excel in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have  folder containing Excel work books.
So , I have manage to get the FileName along with their Full Fledge Name 
Now i want to fetch sheets  within  every Excel Work  Book.

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: I have  tried using [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395541/How-to-load-data-from-multiple-Excel-sheets-to-any) but it doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work.   **BZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZT**. Never say **doesn't work**. explain what happened and what you were expecting.